# Wordpress Add New Post shows this "Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 7589"

Tags: linux, wordpress

I recently migrated my website to new AWS ec2 linux instance. Php8.0, MySql8.0, all pages work fine. Wordpress database was exported from Mysql5.7 and imported to MySql8.0. The blog display and other parts of Wordpress works fine. But when I click 'Add New Post' I am getting these errors. Wordpress is latest 5.9.3.

---

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 7589

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 7590

Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 7594

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 7837

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3502

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/mu-plugins/endurance-page-cache.php on line 544

Warning: Attempt to read property "public" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/mu-plugins/endurance-page-cache.php on line 544

Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack_vendor/automattic/jetpack-sync/src/modules/class-posts.php on line 557

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/theme.php on line 3727

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 5375

Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 5375

Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 4676

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "post_content" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-admin/includes/post.php:742 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/blog/wp-admin/post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit('post', true) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/blog/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 742
```

---

If I disable the errors in my.conf the page goes into an endless loop and finally displays 'Gateway Timeout'.

Comment: Your mu plugin is probably the cause... read the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There was only one plugin 'endurance page cache plugin' inside the mu plugins folder. I renamed the folder and checked, those 2 errors from endurance cache plugin disappeared, but all other errors still exist. Looks like variable initialization issue because of mysql8.0 . Not sure if Wordpress 5.9.3 is compatible with MySql8.0

Comment: Did you find a solution?
because it get the same error:
Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "post_content" on null
and it is inside the wp-include folder.
i have PHP 8, which version of PHP you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I completely removed WordPress from the server and used WPEngine Plugin to migrate my WordPress website to new hosting server. Luckily I still had access to the old server and by website files, so I could do this. Everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a PHP version issue. Try to switch to PHP 7.4

Comment: Why do you think that? `Attempt to read property "public" on null` does not sound like switching the PHP version would resolve that null variable to anything else