# Can't add new page or post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

When I try adding new page or post on my WordPress website on a local server, it gives me this error saying:

> Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\visa\wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 756
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "post_content" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\visa\wp-admin\includes\post.php:795 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\visa\wp-admin\post-new.php(66): get_default_post_to_edit('post', true) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\visa\wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 795  "

Am using PHP version: 8.2.4
Current version of WordPress: 6.4.1

I have tried many solutions, but the same result. What can I try next?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This questions duplicates this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976648/wordpress-add-new-post-shows-this-warning-attempt-to-read-property-post-type).

I am not a WP expert, but I try to answer.

The problem occurs because probably you changed from PHP 7 to PHP 8 and this version fail with fatal error where PHP 7 indicated "only" a warning.

Of course this is not the root cause of your problem, because on PHP 7 probably not worked fine as well.

The root cause of your problem can be a database or theme/plugin issues as described in the forum answers. Please check the forum links below.

These may help you fix your problem:

1. You could try using a tool like phpMyAdmin to inspect the wp_posts table in your database and see if there are any missing or null values in the post_content field.
2. For me this error was due DB importing error. Posts table had no index set on ID field. Maybe it helps someone.
3. What worked for me was fully deleting the production database (rather than simply dropping the tables and importing into it) and creating a fresh database before importing my .sql file.
4. access your server via SFTP or FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel (consult your hosting provider’s documentation for specifics on these), navigate to `/wp-content/themes/` and rename the directory of your currently active theme

Links:

1. [Can’t create new posts/pages (PHP-problem?)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-create-new-posts-pages-php-problem/)
2. [Fatal error can not create posts](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-can-not-create-posts/)
3. [Cannot create new posts of any type on production but everything works fine locally.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/11mx6wi/please_help_cannot_create_new_posts_of_any_type/)
4. [WordPress Add New Post shows this "Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in /var/www/html/blog/wp-includes/post.php on line 7589"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976648/wordpress-add-new-post-shows-this-warning-attempt-to-read-property-post-type)
5. [PHP8 Attempt to read property “post_content” on null](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php8-attempt-to-read-property-post_content-on-null/)

You can also check the documentation of the [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) function in WP.

Comment: Stack Overflow [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to *quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them*. Please update your question by summarizing explanations referenced from links with attributions where possible.